# Changing state with Ajax call in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, state

Upon clicking 'complete' on an item, i would like the item to swap down from the pending section to the completed section of my table.  The complete works, but how would i accomplish this feet with ajax / js?  My ajax is all hooked up, I'm just unsure of the javascript required to show the state change, if someone could point me in the right direction. :)

todo_items_controller.rb

```
def complete
  @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
  @todo_item.complete!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_url }
    format.js
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<table id="todo-items">
  <% if @todo_items.any? %>
    <% @todo_items.pending.each do |item| %>
      <%= render 'todo_items/todo_item', todo_list: @todo_list, item: item %>
    <% end %>

  <% if @todo_items.completed.any? %>   
    <tr><td><h4>Completed</h4></td></tr>
    <% @todo_items.completed.each do |item| %>
      <%= render 'todo_items/completed_todo_item', todo_list: @todo_list, item: item %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

_completed_todo_item.html.erb

```
<tr height="30px">
  <td><%= time_ago_in_words(item.completed_at) + ' ago' %></td>
  <td><%= item.content %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'X', [@todo_list, item], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete?" } %></td>
</tr>
```

complete.js.erb >> currently just places the completed item at the top of the table

```
$('#todo-items tr:first').after('<%= j render 'todo_items/completed_todo_item', todo_list: @todo_list, item: @todo_item %>');
```

but how would i move it down to the completed.any? iteration?

Comment: Could you post your todo_item model?  Specifically, how do you differentiate between a pending and completed task... is it a column in the table?

Comment: @JTG they are scoped, completed where completed_at is not null, and pending where completed_at is null.  when the 'complete' button is clicked, the todo item gets scoped as completed.

Comment: i suppose making two separate tables would be a work-around